# Variable decremantation of a Math.random ensuring non-rrepetitiveness?

Tags: java

I understand this is probably a noobie's question, but I can't wrap my head around it for like 30 minutes now.
I do not understand how this code manages to exclude the possibility of repeating a Math.random result.

This part:

```
chosenNumbers[rundom] = chosenNumbers[biggestNumber - 1];
biggestNumber--;
```

Somehow ensures that no number will be repeated. Can someone tell me how does it work? Does it change the value of "biggestNumber" for each every loop? And if so, Math.random can still draw a number that even multiplied by a decremented "biggestNumber" will be the exact same number that was drawn before, by multiplying by initially larger "biggestNumber".

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("How many numbers do you need to draw?");
    int numbersToDraw = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is the biggest number?");
    int biggestNumber = sc.nextInt();

    int[] chosenNumbers = new int[biggestNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < chosenNumbers.length; i++){
        chosenNumbers[i] = i + 1;
    }

    int[] result = new int[numbersToDraw];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        int rundom = (int) (Math.random() * biggestNumber);
        result[i] = chosenNumbers[rundom];
        chosenNumbers[rundom] = chosenNumbers[biggestNumber - 1];
        biggestNumber--;
    }

    Arrays.sort(result);
    System.out.println("Choose the following numbers to get so really rich.");
    for(int r : result){
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code keeps an array of possible values -- chosenNumbers -- and uses a random number as an index into the array. Once the value is used, it removes it from the list. Even if you get the same random number again, the value at that spot will now be from that spot + 1.

For instance, if biggestNumber is 10, the array contains the values {1, 2, 3, ..., 10}.

Say you get random number 2. chosenNumbers[2] is actually 3 (because arrays index at 0), so you add 3 to the output. But then the code shifts chosenNumbers[3] -> [2], [4] -> [3], etc. So the 3 that used to be in [2] is now gone and can't be selected again.